# Encoding scheme identification of the following communication message

Tags: encryption, encodings

I'm trying to RE an app for educational purposes.
So here is the behavior of the app.

When the app starts, it communicate with a server in plain `tcp` and based on those `tcp` messages, it either work as intended or it stops. I need to understand this communication in order to know the behavior.

I'm able to intercept the messages in `wireshark`, here is the snap of a single message from client to server.
[image: snapshot]

These are printable ASCII characters so its probably not encrypted. I need to understand this communication.

I'm pasting here a chunk of the above message in case someone needs a copy-past:

```
Uxr'6upap,r#G#$G{s@$'xpvUe{wBo4gZ]/y%+pqp r*~   8]i'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpu@WW[Avt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upttq/ZyMxpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq&U}29\hZ`P|%u,]qSk]4StebleYyb6Yoa+}R\~.hJR~a#3JHdo/
Z_yRT
[UYvlm(BT%Gk!AS]VPvx    dZ
]fqBc"uDUr]JzX0j3wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#tua0-xgu07z(/dv!c\'X\^Wruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"C|t|Q~S/taR|dQw[~xvf`]ubd'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'qq#wqr'"upqp r#q##qy'sv 'xpvpt$ruvt%rwt'q
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why you are not sure it's not encrypted? That string has no meaning. I suggest reverse engineering the app that send that tcp traffic

Comment: The consistency of the data says to me that it is encrypted or encoded. The fact there are no visible patterns means that it would be impossible (at least for me) to decode/decrypt just by looking at the data. Also the payload says 1400 bytes which is very close to the 1500 MTU, are you sure this data doesn't continue in the next packet?